# Is it standard to copy collections out of vuex state to prevent mutation?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I’ve scoured the vue forum and there’s a lot of answers that are 2 years old and close, but I’m having a hard time getting one specifically addressing this (I’m simplifying the example):

1. I have an array of objects in state (row data for a table)
2. And a tableComponent with subComponents which for-loops through the data and creates one row per item in the collection
3. The requirement is to add an input to each row in the table which is bound to rowData.foo
4. The tableComponent has a computed property that gets rowData from state, puts those objects into a new (modified) array, and passes it into the tableComponent template
5. Which then adds the input with a v-model of rowData.foo
6. This works, but I recently realized that it is modifying the foo property of a rowData item in the collection without committing a mutation.

I’m ok with dropping v-model and using @input to commit the change, but I have two questions about how this should work

If I want to block these changes until I hit a “confirm changes” button, is it standard / performant to
_.cloneDeep the whole collection in either the tableComponent computed property or in the vuex getter. It seems like a lot of overhead but maybe I’m being too conservative about that?

Allowing v-model to update RowData.foo directly means each row knows which RowData item to modify, now that I’m committing a change to a single object in a vuex collection, is the best practice to make the vuex mutation _.find the object, change it, and then spread the whole collection back into the store?

As with most of my other vue questions, I have multiple ways that make it work, but I’m not sure what the most performant/best pattern is. Thanks for any help!

**Update**
Simple codeSandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/embed/vuex-store-olrvk
See how the vuex data is updated without an action call?

Comment: please include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I can work on that, but the real question is: should components be working with vuex store collections directly or with copies of them

Comment: yes they should access or mutate the store data directly

Comment: I added the minimal reproducible example. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reviewing your codeSandbox sample i found that YES your store state data `rowCollection` is getting mutated without using any mutation and that's because of the `v-model` (two-way binding) that detects the data spot in memory and mutates it behind the scenes ... of course this was allowed by Vue devs even tough i couldn't find about this at any document (and by the way on the doc they showed an example of a state mutation using `v-model` but they used a store mutation for that )  [image]

and concerning  `what is the most performant/best pattern` i think this way is the easiest and much cleaner (less code)

Comment: Thank you very much. Both your answer and Steven's are super helpful

Comment: Thank you too , i didn't know either that the store mutation is possible without using a mutation ... they should really consider about such things because they matter a lot at bigger apps if they really want there framework to hold up

Answer (score 1):

If you need to buffer user changes to a reactive model (for a commit operation), you will need to make a deep copy.  There is no way around it.  Totally normal.

Comment: Thank you very much. Both your answer and Dadboz's are super helpful